# How to retrieve the 'scheme://domain' part of a generic URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.10 and I would like to retrieve the `scheme://domain` part of a generic URL (note: a URL syntax can be also [`scheme://domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax)).

That is, for example, if I have the following URLs

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304043/how-to-retrieve-the-scheme-domainport-part-of-a-generic-url
ftp://some_link.org/some_other_string

# Consider also 'https', 'ftps' and so on... 'scheme:' values.
```

I would like to retrieve just the

```
# Note: The last '/' character was removed.

http://stackoverflow.com
ftp://some_link.org

# Consider also 'https', 'ftps' and so on... 'scheme:' values.
```

parts. **How can I do that?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304043/how-to-retrieve-the-scheme-domainport-part-of-a-generic-url")
url = "#{uri.scheme}://#{uri.host}" #url would be set to http://stackoverflow.com
```

From [Module: URI](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/URI.html#M001616).

Comment: BTW: Is the 'uri' module required by default? In 'development' mode if I do not require that module my application still works... why?

Comment: @Backo Perhaps [Rails Autoload Modules](http://www.williambharding.com/blog/technology/rails-3-autoload-modules-and-classes-in-production/) may be of interest...

Comment: Yeah, you don't have to explicitly require it. Was just doing so to be thorough :)

Comment: @Vibhu - Thanks. There is a way to know what Classes and Modules are loaded in\from Ruby by default?